# WPAlchemy Media Thickbox goes blank on pressing 'Insert into post'

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, image-upload

I have added the WPAlchemy Media Access class to my locally hosted WAMP Wordpress site, added as shown at this link: http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-media-uploader-integration/

I have then added this to my Custom Post by using 'types' under the WPAlchemy 'custom-spec.php' file like so:

```
<?php

$custom_mb = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
'id' => '_custom_meta',
'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
'types' => array('post','my_custom_post'),
'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/custom-meta.php',
));

/* eof */
```

If I go to wordpress default post editor pressing the image upload button brings up the media thickbox, I upload a new image and then press 'insert into post' button and all works fine the link to the image appears in the meta box.

However, if I go to the post editor for one of my 'custom post' pages the meta box for image upload appears okay, pressing the button calls up the thickbox media page okay, uploading image works, but when you press 'Insert into post' the thickbox page goes blank (white) and nothing happens. You can close the thickbox modal by clicking outside etc but the image link does not get added to the image input field in the same way it did in the normal post editor?

Because it works in the standard Wordpress post editor I think perhaps the problem lies with adding the upload functionality to a custom post type but I just can't find where the problem lies in the code and a solution to fixing this. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Disable all plugins and swap to the default theme. Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). Check for Javascript errors.

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo. I ran the same process again but with Firebug Console on and at the point I press 'Add into post' and thickbox goes blank this error is returned in Firebug: TypeError: win.send_to_editor is not a function.  

var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;Looks like this is somewhere in wp-admin/media-upload.php. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution to my problem, not sure if it's the best solution but it seems to be working for me. Here's a link: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/solution-for-media-upload-not-working-on-post-edit-page

Just involves adding the following under your functions.php file.

```
function enable_media_upload(){
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'enable_media_upload' );
```